# PHP Array of Price Ranges - Retrieve the lowest and highest

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working with a PHP array that shows a range of prices, where an individual item is in the form of "price from-price to". Here's an example of the array:

```
Array
(
[0] => $625,000-$700,000
[1] => $550,000-$625,000
[2] => $1,000,000-$1,250,000
[3] => $925,000-$1,000,000
)
```

I now need to retrieve the lowest and highest price in the array, however as they are a range I first need to pull apart each price in each array item. For example using the above array I would like to be able to return something like this:

```
$minPrice = 550000;
$maxPrice = 1250000;
```

I'm new to PHP and completely stumped at this point about how to go about parsing each of the values from each array item then getting the lowest/highest value.

Comment: Don't store your values with the dollar sign and also I would make a multidimensional array, e.g. `Array(Array([min] => [max] => ), ...)`

Comment: I don't have control over the format of the array unfortunately - it's coming from an external source that I can't change

Comment: Then the external source sucks. Split the values removes the dollar sign and rearrange your array structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put all the normalized prices in an array and use the php max, min functions.

```
<?php

$ranges = array(
 "$625,000-$700,000",
 "$550,000-$625,000",
 "$1,000,000-$1,250,000",
 "$925,000-$1,000,000",
);

$prices = array();
foreach ($ranges as $range) {
    $prices = array_merge($prices, explode("-", preg_replace("/[\\$,]/i", "", $range)));
}

$maxPrice = max($prices);
$minPrice = min($prices);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $array = Array
            (
             0 => '$625,000-$700,000',
             1 => '$550,000-$625,000',
             2 => '$1,000,000-$1,250,000',
             3 => '$925,000-$1,000,000',
            );

    $tmp = array(); 

    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        $cleanValue =  explode('-', str_replace(array('$',','), array('',''), $value));
        foreach($cleanValue as $k=>$v){
            $tmp[] = $v;
        }

    }



    $minValue = min($tmp);
    $maxValue = max($tmp);

    echo $minValue .  ' '. $maxValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer code below.

First value are exploded to an array and then "$" is removed and then value is converted to integer. Then values are added to array and finally min / max functions are called.

```
$maxPrice = 0;
$max_curr = 0;
$price_arr = array();

foreach($min_maxs as $min_max){

    $min_max_arr = explode("-",$min_max); // string to array

    array_walk($min_max_arr,"remove_dollar_commas"); // remove "$"

    $price_arr = array_merge($price_arr , $min_max_arr ); // add to final array

}        

$maxPrice = max($price_arr); // call max function to get maximum value
$minPrice = min($price_arr); // call min function to get minimum value

function remove_dollar_commas(&$subject){
    $subject = intval( str_replace(array("\$",","), "", $subject) );        
}
```